# Reading in high dimensional data into R without use of data frame

Tags: r, data-mining, classification, text-mining

I have very sparse high dimensional (40k observations, 20k dimensions) text data in [ARFF](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+(stable+version)) format generated by 
[WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/).

There are 2 ARFF readers available in R via [RWeka](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RWeka) and [foreign](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreign/index.html) packages. Problem with both these arff readers is that they read in the arff data into a data frame (and hence you go from sparse data to a non-sparse way of storage), and since my data set is rather large, neither if these is a practical way. In fact I start to run out of memory while RWeka tries to read in the arff file.

So the questions are:

(1) What is a suitable way to store and process my data under R? Please note that I am reading in labeled text data since I want to do text classification. So any sparse representation should (ideally) be usable as is by the classifiers.

(2) More importantly, how do I read in my arff file in that format (as in question 1) then?

Thanks in advance.

--Edits--

Extract of my ARFF file as requested in one of the comments:

```
@relation train.arff-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.StringToWordVector-R1-W100000-prune-rate-1.0-I-N1-L-stemmerweka.core.stemmers.LovinsStemmer-M1-tokenizerweka.core.tokenizers.AlphabeticTokenizer
@attribute myclasses {alpha, beta, gamma, delta}
@attribute aardvark numeric
@attribute abbrevi numeric
@attribute abduc numeric
@data
{102 7.686363,166 6.302574,791 9.204264,1854 1.370962,2830 5.907602}
{1727 14.842519}
{103 0.774816,289 2.874456,413 3.729545,517 4.723478,1286 1.417374,1531 3.23805,1637 4.534334,1708 3.544581,1854 0.961008,1878 3.731564,2105 7.701038,2209 4.83372,2466 5.663894}
{1 1.368628,103 0.582774,225 5.61684,954 5.792294,1082 5.194097,1160 5.792294,1799 4.367975,1854 0.722817,2220 4.114164,2304 2.967602,2456 3.186834,2564 0.701145,2839 6.039582}
```

Comment: See answers to the closely related question [Discrete and Continuous Classifier on Sparse Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500467/discrete-and-continuous-classifier-on-sparse-data)

Comment: @Itamar: Well my question is more along the lines of how to read in the sparse data into R.

Comment: Please post an extract of the ARFF data you are encountering.  I can address (1), but to answer (2) will be easier if I am sure I'm not making a mistake.  Basically, being able to reproduce the problem will be very helpful for arriving at a good answer.

Comment: @Iterator: I posted a small extract of my ARFF. I can make the whole (big) arff file available if need be.

Answer (score 0):

How you read the data depends on what data structure the analysis uses. I would therefor start by looking for packages that can deal with sparse data (see [Discrete and Continuous Classifier on Sparse Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500467/discrete-and-continuous-classifier-on-sparse-data)). As mentioned in the replies to this question Weka supports sparse ARFF data (see [Handling Large Data Sets with Weka](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/Handling+Large+Data+Sets+with+Weka) on [Pentaho](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/DATAMINING/Pentaho+Data+Mining+Community+Documentation)).